# I need English books about chess which are in the public domain and still have value to the current chess improver to translate to arabic legally

Tags: books

I need English books about chess which are in the public domain and still have value to the current chess improver to translate to Arabic legally.
they must be of a value for the current chess improver.

Comment: Have you tried [Gutenberg project](https://www.gutenberg.org)? A quick search by "chess" gives some results Like Capablanca's "Chess fundamentals" and Edward Lasker's "Chess strategy".

Comment: There's Nimzovich's "My System" but I'd bet it's already been translated into every language imaginable